# How do I calculate the standard uncertainty? Task on determination of energy gap width of semiconductors

Tags: electricity, semiconductor-physics, error-analysis

I am creating a report for my physics class and all I have left to do is calculate the standard uncertainty for this formula.

$$ \ln \left( \frac{R_{T}}{R_{\infty}} \right) = \ln \left( R_{T} \right) - \ln \left( R_{\infty} \right)$$

From linear regression I know that $\ln \left( R_{\infty} \right) = b$ in one of NTC termistors in case of heating it is $u \left( b \right) = 0.165193075$ (its an uncertainty of this val) its calculated with REGLIMP fun in excel.

But my uncertainty for one of NTC termistors in case of heating in $R_{1}$ is equal to $0.534$ so $\ln \left( R_{1} \right)$ for it is negative.

If someone can help I would very appreciate that.

$$ R_{T} = R_{\infty} e^{\frac{W_{g}}{2 k T}} $$

And its a formula for calculating energy break.

1. $k$ - is a Boltzmanna const in $eV$
2. $R_{\infty}$ - resistance at temperature going to infinity
3. $T$ - temperature (expressed in Kelvin)
4. $W_{g}$ - energy gap value

Comment: Have you checked / looked-up how to do error analysis, if functions are involved?